# Equation with Parameter

Tags: real-analysis

I want to solve a seemingly simple equation:

$k+(k-2)*x = (2k+3)x-2x-3$

wolfram alpha says that k = -3 and x = 1 - but I don't see yet how I arrive 
at this solution.

Thanks

Comment: are the solutions restricted to integers ?

Comment: Does the "$*$" means multiplication?

Comment: yes, and yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the equation
$$k + kx -2x = 2kx + 3x -2x -3$$
$$k-kx =3x-3$$
$$k(1-x)=-3(1-x)$$
$$k(1-x)+3(1-x)=0$$
$$(k+3)(1-x)=0$$

Comment: Hm, but then k = 3 and x = 1, whereas according to wolfram alpha k = -3 ....

Comment: @newbie check your last line

Comment: @Michael oops. Thanks.

Comment: now I agree. Thanks

Comment: one more question: how do I get from the second last line to the last line? It is not obvious to me at first sight